# node js : test rest API

Tags: node.js

i'm new learner in backend node js ... in my code below i created an API for questions and it contains get,post,delete and edit
i wanted to test it using the extension rest client in VS code but when i type Get `http://localhost:3000/api` in route.rest file to test it,it stucks on waiting

is there a way to know if my API works good and can somebody please help me if i have mistake below?

thanks in advance

```js
//server.js

// @ts-nocheck
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');


const questionRoutes = require('./routes/subscribers');

const cors = require('cors');
const http = require('http');
 // Has to be move but later
const multer = require("multer");

const Question = require('./models/subscriber');

// express app
const app = express();

// Explicitly accessing server
const server = http.createServer(app);

// corsfffffffff
app.use(cors());

dotenv.config();

 const dbURI = process.env.MONGO_URL || "mongodb://localhost:27017/YourDB";

mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(result => server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000) )
 
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// register view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.json);

// middleware & static files
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.path = req.path;
  next();
});

// routes

// question routes
app.use('/questions' , questionRoutes );

// 404 page
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404).render('404', { title: '404' });
});
```

```js
//questionRoute.js

const express = require('express');
const questionController = require('../controllers/questionCon');
const questionApiController = require('../controllers/questionApiController');

const router = express.Router();

// API Routing

router.get('/api/', questionApiController.get_questions);
router.post('/api/add', questionApiController.create_question);
router.get('/api/:id', questionApiController.get_question);
router.delete('/api/delete/:id', questionApiController.delete_question);
router.put('/api/update/:id', questionApiController.update_question);

// EJS Routing for GUI

router.get('/create', questionController.question_create_get);
router.get('/', questionController.question_index);
router.post('/', questionController.question_create_post);
router.get('/:id', questionController.question_details);
router.delete('/:id', questionController.question_delete);


module.exports = router;
```

```js
//question.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const questionSchema = new Schema({
  questionTitle: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },


  description: {
    type: String,

  },
  price: {
    type: Number,

  },
});

const Question = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema);
module.exports = Question;
```

```js
//questionAPIcontroller


const Question = require('../models/subscriber');

const  validators  = require('../validators');
let questionApiController = {

    
  // Get a single question

  get_question : async (req , res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;

    try {
        const question = await Question.findById(id,(err, question) => {
          
          if (err) return res.status(400).json({response : err});
          res.send("hello")
          res.status(200).json({response : question})
        console.log("hello")
      })
  
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json(err);
    }
  },

  // Get all the questions

  get_questions: async (req , res) => {
    try {
      const questions = await Question.find((err, questions) => {
          
        if (err) return res.status(400).json({response : err});
        
        res.status(200).json({response : questions})
        
    })
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json(err);
    }
  },

  // Create a question
  create_question : async (req , res) => {

    const {error} = validators.postQuestionValidation(req.body);
    if(error) return res.status(400).json({ "response" : error.details[0].message})

    try {
      const question = await new Question(req.body);

    question.save((err, question) => {
          
      if (err) return res.status(400).json({response : err});
      
      res.status(200).json({response : " Question created Successfully"})
      
  });

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json(err);
    }
  },
  // Delete question


    
  delete_question : async (req , res) => {

    const id = req.params.id;

    var questionExist = false;
    var userId ;

    const question = await Question.findById(id).then(result => {
      questionExist = true;
      userId = result.owner;
    }).catch(err => {
      questionExist = false;
      res.status(400).json({response : err });
    });

    

    if(questionExist){
      try {
        Question.findByIdAndRemove(id ,(err, question) => {
          // As always, handle any potential errors:
          if (err) return res.json({response : err});
          // We'll create a simple object to send back with a message and the id of the document that was removed
          // You can really do this however you want, though.
          const response = {
              message: "Question successfully deleted",
              id: question._id
          };
          return res.status(200).json({response : response });
      });
  
     
       
      } catch (err) {
          res.status(400).json(err);
      }
    }

    else {

      return res.status(400).send( { "response" : "A question with that id was not find."});
    }    

  },


  // Update question

  update_question : async (req , res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    Question.findByIdAndUpdate(id,req.body,
      function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            res.status(400).json({response : err});
          } else {
            res.status(200).json({response : "Question Updated"}); 
            console.log(result);
          }
        })
  },



  // Get question's questions



}


module.exports = questionApiController
```

```js
//questionController

const Question = require('../models/subscriber');

const question_index = (req, res) => {
  Question.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .then(result => {
      res.render('index', { questions: result, title: 'All questions' });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

const question_details = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  Question.findById(id)
    .then(result => {
      res.render('details', { question: result, title: 'Question Details' });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.render('404', { title: 'Question not found' });
    });
}

const question_create_get = (req, res) => {
  res.render('create', { title: 'Create a new question' });
}

const question_create_post = (req, res) => {
  const question = new Question(req.body);
  question.save()
    .then(result => {
      res.redirect('/questions');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

const question_delete = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  Question.findByIdAndDelete(id)
    .then(result => {
      res.json({ redirect: '/questions' });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

module.exports = {
  question_index, 
  question_details, 
  question_create_get, 
  question_create_post, 
  question_delete
}
```

Comment: Please boil your code down to meet the standards of creating a [mre]. Also, please don't use Stack Snippets for non-browser JavaScript code, as in most cases it will not run the way you desire and does not assist in debugging the issue.

Answer (score 1):

change code

```js
app.use(express.json);
```

to

```js
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: i got this ,,,,  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 112
ETag: W/"70-kjmb9K5NSiqVq1t4jNLT6p3OhRw"
Date: Fri, 03 Dec 2021 14:30:44 GMT
Connection: close

<html lang="en">

<body>

  <div class="not-found content">
    OOPS, page not found :)
  </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Yeah of cource. You didn't registered any router for `/`.
make request for `/questions`

Comment: throws another error ,,,,,,  8|     <h2>All Blogs</h2>
    9|
 >> 10|     <% if (blogs.length > 0) { %>
    11|       <% blogs.forEach(blog => { %>
    12|         <a class="single" href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>">
    13|           <h3 class="title"><%= blog.title %></h3>

blogs is not defined

Comment: and i registered /api in routes but when tested `http://localhost:3000/api`  it gaves me 404

Comment: there seems that you missed some context variable in your ejs router. and I don't know what did you actually add in `/api`... so I cannot help for the second question